# Why ser.readline data not appear in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

I was using a sensor that connect to arduino and using ser.readline() to print reading from sensor and success. But when I want to send the reading value using ser.readline to mysql. It only pass the device name and current time and the value of the reading that show in mysql is '0'. Here my coding.

```
import time
import serial
import smtplib
import datetime
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.103", "fyp", "123456", "system")
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while True:
      api = ser.readline()
      current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
      print (api)

      sql = "INSERT INTO reading (series_no, time, api) VALUES ('test1', current_time, api)"
      data = (current_time, api)
      cur.execute(sql)

db.close()
```

Using %s is not work either. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You are not parameterizing the query correctly*. Several things to fix:

- add placeholders for the query parameters - `%s`, no quotes around
- pass the `data` tuple to `execute()`
- commit the transaction

Fixed version:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO reading (series_no, time, api) VALUES ('test1', %s, %s)"
data = (current_time, api)
cur.execute(sql, data)
db.commit()
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But why at first it say 'Warning: Data truncated from column 'api' at row 1'

Comment: @Hazim let's see - what is(are) the value(s) of `api` and what is the `api` table column type? Thanks.

Comment: I not really sure what my api value. But it print '25, 28', so I just assume it as integer in table column.

Comment: @Hazim well, let's solve it separately - consider creating a new question is you need help figuring that out. Before though, make sure to search the web and SO - you might find the answer right away. If you will do create a question, make sure to provide the table's "create table" query so that others would see the column types. Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks sir.